# Getting key error while trying to acces a list with the help of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

So im making a game where im supposed to take an input and remove something from a list. Can anyone see what's wrong with my indexing here? I just get a keyerror. How do i write it to not get that keyerror. I want to make my input, for example AB into numbers so that the program will remove the last element of the list that is associated with that number by indexing then using the .pop(). In this case AB will remove the last element of the lists called pile1 and pile2, but i can't get that to work. Please comment on how i phrase the question too. English is not my first language and im not very used to coding. Any and all help is appreciated

```
import random
SPAR_SYMBOL = '\u2660'
RUTER_SYMBOL = '\u2666'
KLØVER_SYMBOL = '\u2663'
HJERTER_SYMBOL = '\u2665'
kortstokk = []


pile1 = []
pile2 = []
pile3 = []
pile4 = []
pile5 = []
pile6 = []
pile7 = []
pile8 = []
for kort in range(7, 15):
    kortstokk.append(f'\u2660{kort}')
    kortstokk.append(f'\u2666{kort}')
    kortstokk.append(f'\u2663{kort}')
    kortstokk.append(f'\u2665{kort}')


piles = [[pile1], [pile2], [pile3], [pile4],
          [pile5], [pile6], [pile7], [pile8]]


def del_ut():
    random.shuffle(kortstokk)
    for j in range(4):
        for i in range(8):
            if i == 0:
                pile1.append(kortstokk.pop())
            elif i == 1:
                pile2.append(kortstokk.pop())
            elif i == 2:
                pile3.append(kortstokk.pop())
            elif i == 3:
                pile4.append(kortstokk.pop())
            elif i == 4:
                pile5.append(kortstokk.pop())
            elif i == 5:
                pile6.append(kortstokk.pop())
            elif i == 6:
                pile7.append(kortstokk.pop())
            elif i == 7:
                pile8.append(kortstokk.pop())


def tap():
    # Start spillet på nytt med input eller gå til meny med annen input
    pass


def seier():
    # Ved seier skal spilleren få et output i terminalen som sier feks. Gratulerer du vant
    # Seier skjer hvis alle bunker er tomme

    pass


def lagre():
    # Lagre fil

    # Finn ut hvilket format som skal brukes ved lagring av fil for spillet
    pass


def last_inn():
    # åpne lagret fil
    pass


def spill():
    del_ut()
    while True:
        print("A: ", piles[0][-1][-1])
        print("B: ", piles[1][-1][-1])
        print("C: ", piles[2][-1][-1])
        print("D: ", piles[3][-1][-1])
        print("E: ", piles[4][-1][-1])
        print("F: ", piles[5][-1][-1])
        print("G: ", piles[6][-1][-1])
        print("H: ", piles[7][-1][-1])
        velg_kort()
spill()
piles = [[pile1], [pile2], [pile3], [pile4],[pile5], [pile6], [pile7], [pile8]]
def choose_card():
    global piles
    cards = input("choose two piles of cards: ")
    change= {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'G': 6, 'H': 7}
    if len(cards) == 2:
        v1 = change[cards[0]]
        v2 = change[cards[1]]
        remove_card(v1, v2)
    elif len(cards) < 2:
        print("Invalid input.")

def remove_card(v1, v2):
    global piles
    change = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'G': 6, 'H': 7}
    if v1 != v2 and piles[change[v1]][-1][-1][-1] == piles[change[v2]][-1][-1][-1]:
        piles[change[v1]].pop(-1)
        piles[change[v2]].pop(-1)
```

Comment: What are you trying to get when you put `piles[change[v1]][-1][-1][-1]`

Comment: I was trying to get the last element of that specific list. If im going to remove from both lists the last element needs to be the same. But even without it i still get the keyerror. @ErikMcKelvey

Answer (score 0):

In this code in choose_card :

```
if len(cards) == 2:
    v1 = change[cards[0]]
    v2 = change[cards[1]]
    remove_card(v1, v2)
```

v1 and v2 are numbers from 0 to 7 and when you call remove_card(v1,v2) :

```
def remove_card(v1, v2):
    global piles
    change = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'G': 6, 'H': 7}
    if v1 != v2 and piles[change[v1]]…
```

Here change[v1] and change[v2] does not exists .

Correction 1 : send v1 and v2 as cards not index

```
def choose_card():
    global piles
    cards = input("choose two piles of cards: ")
    #change= {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'G': 6, 'H': 7} # no more needed except if you want to check for valid input
    if len(cards) == 2:
        v1 = cards[0] # just pass user input
        v2 = cards[1] # just pass user input
        remove_card(v1, v2)
    elif len(cards) < 2:
        print("Invalid input.")

def remove_card(v1, v2):
    global piles
    change = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'G': 6, 'H': 7}
    if v1 != v2 and piles[change[v1]][-1][-1][-1] == piles[change[v2]][-1][-1][-1]:
        piles[change[v1]][-1].pop(-1) # changed missing index
        piles[change[v2]][-1].pop(-1) # changed missing index
```

Other correction possibility : remove_cards deals with indexes :

```
def choose_card():
    global piles
    cards = input("choose two piles of cards: ")
    change= {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'G': 6, 'H': 7}
    if len(cards) == 2:
        v1 = change[cards[0]]
        v2 = change[cards[1]]
        remove_card(v1, v2)
    elif len(cards) < 2:
        print("Invalid input.")

def remove_card(v1, v2):
    global piles
    #change = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'G': 6, 'H': 7} # no more needed as input is pile index
    if v1 != v2 and piles[v1][-1][-1][-1] == piles[v2][-1][-1][-1]:
        piles[v1][-1].pop(-1) # changed missing index
        piles[v2][-1].pop(-1) # changed missing index
```

Now still missing :

- check input validity :

  - card pile is A..H
  - there is at least one card in pile

Comment: I dont understand. What should i do here?

Comment: i do not know what you have in piles but it should be last element of piles[v1] == last element of piles[v2] as v1 and v2 are already index .

Comment: In the piles i have cards stored as strings because they have a symbol too. Would you like to see the entire code so you can run the program with cards?

Comment: I added 2 different ways that could correct your code (use only one not both)

Comment: I don't understand what to change, i tried as you said but now i just get this message: print("F: ", bunker[5][-1][-1])
IndexError: list index out of range. Do you have like a total rewrite you can make? sorry for being so difficult!

Comment: I added what was needed to "play"

Comment: @Sondre : I updated my answer. You also will have some work to prevent code from failure in case of invalid input.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I finally got it all to work:)